# Visual Studio does not show in which line error is

Tags: c++, debugging, vector

When I am programming in C++ and Visual Studio 2019 throws an error, it shows in which line it was encountered. But when coding with C++ when error is thrown, it does not show in which line exactly it appears. So it makes hard to debug and fix my program. Maybe there are settings that I need to adjust?

C++ error (it point to some 1501 line of installation files that weren't created by me):

```
 vector<int> myVector(2);
 cout << myVector[4] << endl;
```

[image: C++ error view]

Errors in both programs in these examples are of a same category: vector (in C++).

Comment: I just thought that it might be because of project template itself? I use .NET Framework for C# and just a simple ConsoleApp for C++

Comment: Please only ask one question. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), before posting a question. Also you'll need to show a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @GenoC I asked one question, no? How to fix my settings (or something) to see in which line I have error. I dont know what is the problem, so how should I ask?

Comment: Thats not how it works, You are doing something wrong with the vectors yourself so the vector library is throwing an error, we can't help you if you don't show us your code as we don't know what went wrong.

Comment: The C++ error is showing you the line it has asserted on. Your best bet from that is to have a look at the callstack and see where the subscript operator is being called from.

Comment: I added a code now please take a look :)

Comment: There's no setting to make this magically "work". You can either assert yourself `ASSERT( 4 < myVector.size() );`, or [have a look at visual studios debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019), the callstack is the thing that's particularly useful for this sort of crash.

Comment: "Magical setting" is to click Retry instead of Abort and  go to(or open) "call stack" window to see where problem happens". Oh, and code shown is an Undefined Behavior. operator[] doesn't allocate new items  for vector.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I understand that the code I provided has a mistake. I try to print undefined item. That is the point. I would like the program to point to the exact line where the problem is. Just like in C#

Comment: C# translates your code into virtual instructions  while C++ creates code for actual hardware... your incorrect code created problem elsewhere.. because distinction between your code and execution exists in CLI, you get nearest position in your code. In C++ any header that included and any library you linked is part of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Without providing more code and looking at the minimal `c++` code you provided:

```
vector<int> myVector(2);
cout << myVector[4] << endl;
```

It looks like you have too many elements in `myVector` in the second line. You will have UB because the `[]` operator does not allocated more elements. You only declared 2 elements.

Now, when you send your `vector` to `cout` you are saying you have 4 which is *false*.

That is why you are getting the error: *"Expression: vector subscript out of range"*.

You only have two indices 0 and 1, if you define a `vector` with 2 `elements`.

Now if you were trying to see the size of your `vector` you use the `.size()` function which returns the number of elements in the `vector`.

```
vector<int> myVector(2);
cout << myVector.size() << endl;
```

You could even do something like this with a `for` loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myVector(2);
    std::cout << myVector.size() << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        myVector.push_back(i);

    std::cout << myVector.size() << '\n';
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I fully understand why my program crashes. My original question was a little different but then someone edited it as I see... I was asking how can I see in which line exactly the error is happening. In this toy example I see that error is in line 2. But how do I find it in huge program if it only shows outOfRangeExcepttion but does not point into a particular line?

Comment: @vyaute it's runtime errors, they are linked to stack frame and thread, which can follow (and it shows line to you if it is a debug build with program database available), line 1501 in <vector>. You have to do postmortem debugging, see where that stack begins in your code, or trace it.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie, thanks for explaining. I'll delete my answer.